# Codeigniter environments custom javascript inclusion

Tags: codeigniter, version-control, configuration, mercurial, environments

Codeigniter has its 'ENVIRONMENT' setting such that when in a production environment, by changing the setting to 'production', all of the production configuration files are included.

A large amount of my website utilizes javascript. As such I want to have some config such as the below which changes dependent on whether i'm in a local or production environment.

```
<base href="http://localhost/site/" />
<script type="text/javascript">  
var base_url = 'http://localhost/site/';
</script>
```

Does anyone know how i can make codeigniter include config/production/custom-config.php
And if I could, surely that wouldn't be a suitable place for such configuration?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter includes as `base_url`configuration variable located in `application/config/config.php`.  You could do something like this:

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
</script>
```

*Does anyone know how i can make codeigniter include config/production/custom-config.php And if I could, surely that wouldn't be a suitable place for such configuration?*

You can easily create custom config files.  Create a file in the `application/config/` folder (or the appropriate environment folder).  For example:

*application/config/production/custom_config.php:*

```
<?php

$config['custom_var'] = 'custom value';
$config['another_var'] = 'another value';
// ...
```

Then you can load your new configuration file using:

```
$this->load->config('custom_config');
```

And access your configuration variables using:

```
$this->config->item('custom_var');
```

Finally, take a look at the [documentation on the Config Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html).

Comment: Great answer and +1 for including a note about config folders :)